# android custom view redraw

Tags: android, view

I am trying to redraw the custom view in `onCreate()` method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)    
{    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    
        circleView = (CircleView)findViewById(R.id.circleView);    
        circleView.setCircle(100, 100, 25);    
        circleView.wrapView();    
 }
```

and custom view is :

```
public class CircleView extends View  
{  
    private Paint paint = null;  
    private int x = 50;  
    private int y = 50;  
    private int radius = 50;  
    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)   
    {  
        super(context, attrs);  
        init();  
    }  
    public CircleView(Context context)    
    {  
        super(context);  
        init();  
    }  
    private void init()  
    {  
        paint = new Paint();  
    }   
    public void setCircle(int x, int y, int radius)  
    {  
        this.x = x;  
        this.y = y;  
        this.radius = radius;  
        init();  
        this.invalidate();  
    }  
    @Override  
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)   
    {  
        super.onDraw(canvas);  
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);  
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);  
        Log.e("", "radius : " + radius);  
    }  
        public void setColor(int color)  
    {  
        paint.setColor(color);  
    }  
    public void wrapView()   
    {  
        this.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(radius*2, radius*2));  
        this.invalidate();  
    }  
}
```

and xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    >

    <com.pep1439.view.CircleView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/circleView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i just want to resize the circle, but failed. Help me to draw circle with any radius. How to do this. Its working fine if i use default values. It draws the circle when i remove the line `circleView.setCircle(100, 100, 25);`. I want to adjust circle at run time.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `x` and `y` to `100` and radius to `25`. Then you resize your view to `radius*2`, which is `50`, so in the end you're drawing a circle of radius `25` at position `100,100` on a view that is only `50x50` in size. In other words: **You draw your circle outside the area of your view**.

Comment: @Ridcully what is the area inside in pixels/dip. Is there any fix value of custom View width and height

Comment: The size of the view is specified by android:layout_width and android:layout_height. If you use the value 'wrap_content' it is up to the View itself to tell about the size it needs/wants. This is done by by implementing getIntrinsicWidth() and getIntrinsicHeight(). When a Layout lays out its children, it will call those methods to know what size to make the view.